# Cant reference class a NETStandard1.6 class library a Xamarin Android project

Tags: c#, xamarin.android, asp.net-core

So im trying to use a class library that's in `NETStandard1.6` on my Xamarin project but it's not letting me reference it. I have added the assembly reference but when I go to use the classes from the class lib it simply says cannot find the namespace of the class lib. So I made fresh projects for both and still experiencing the same issue.

Here's my `project.json` from the class lib project

```
 "version": "1.0.0-*",

  "dependencies": {
    "NETStandard.Library": "1.6.0"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "netstandard1.6": {
      "imports": "dnxcore50"
    }
  }
```

**Update** so I changed my class library project to a PLC targeting NetStandard1.0 but still having trouble referencing it in a Xamarin project. The reason I thought I might be able to do this is because of the table below, I guess it means this is the intended state for NetStandard?

[image]

**Update** turns out I left my brain at home, after building the project it works fine, both Xamarin and the asp.net core web app can reference the PLC targeting NETStandard1.6 after building the project, this is the part I didn't try doing before

Comment: Those .NET Core bits were released two weeks ago, and you should expect Xamarin to introduce full support in a couple of weeks. Not now.

Comment: @Lex Li Oh my mistake, I was reading through the docs and saw how xamerin is supporting netstandard1.6. I didn't see any times on it so I guess they posted those docs ahead of the release or something

Comment: The .NET Standard document uses "*" for Mono/Xamarin if you carefully read. My understanding is that by far that area is "unknown". Miguel de Icaza (leader of Mono/Xamarin) recently becomes active at GitHub corefx repo, so we probably can expect something good later this year.

Comment: @Lex Li Ahh I must have jumped over the * part, I do remember it but I must have interpreted it as all rather than a note to read more, thanks for pointing that out

Comment: Guess i can just target the full net45 framework for now till they release sonething